# Finding text with Index Match

Tags: excel

I want to find text that is buried in a string. Example:

[image]

If the text in E2 contains any of the keywords listed, then I'd like '1' to be printed in G2.

Repeat the process for the rest of the rows in Column E. There could be 1000 rows.

This is the array formula I used in Excel: `{=COUNTIF(E2,"*" & F:F & "*")}` but it's not working.

If someone could explain what I did wrong, and point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-find-substring-string-python, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm, https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-get-a-substring-from-a-string-in-python-slicing-strings/, https://www.jquery-az.com/2-ways-get-python-substring-strings-5-examples/

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH($F$2,E2),IFERROR(SEARCH($F$3,F2),"NA"))),1,0)
```